# String Parsing Required

Tags: bash, shell

I want to parse a string in bash shell scripting

```
'serverDN'       :'/DC=ch/DC=cern/OU=computers/CN=myserverName', \
```

and result should be like this

```
/DC=ch/DC=cern/OU=computers/CN=myserverName
```

Any help???

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "'serverDN' :'/DC=ch/DC=cern/OU=computers/CN=myserverName', \\" |
  awk -F"'" '{print $4}'
/DC=ch/DC=cern/OU=computers/CN=myserverName
```

Answer (score 3):

Strip off the beginning and the end:

```
string=${string#*:\'}
string=${string%\'*}
```